# Trying to create a .dat on unix using FILENAME statement in SAS

Tags: unix, sas

Tried `filename log_list pipe 'ls -1 /fbrms01/dev/Logs/*.log | xargs grep -l "ERROR:"  > /fbrms01/dev/Logs/log_error.dat';` but `log_error.dat` file is not creating on UNIX.

When I tried

> ls -1 `/fbrms01/dev/Logs/*.log | xargs grep -l "ERROR:"  >
>   /fbrms01/dev/Logs/log_error.dat.

it created `log_error.dat` file on UNIX.

So I'm think there is some thing wrong filename statement.Any suggestions??

Thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the [X statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/63053/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0w7z1ah45wd1sn1kafn6uibm1mu.htm) (run operating system command) is more in line with what you have written.

```
x 'ls -1 /fbrms01/dev/Logs/*.log | xargs grep -l "ERROR:" > /fbrms01/dev/Logs/log_error.dat';
```

PIPE access method sends output from a command to INFILE so there is not need to direct STDOUT to a file.

```
filename log_list pipe 'ls -1 `/fbrms01/dev/Logs/*.log | xargs grep -l "ERROR:"';
data ..;
   infile log_list;
   input  ...;
```